# Run or execute script after page is loaded with react helmet, react gatsbyjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, load, gatsby

i have a blog post page that load content via graphql, in the content are scripts tag of charts.

the problem is that when using  it does not load the scripts. Only load the scripts if you refresh the browser.

So i added the scripts to helmet after data loaded but they dont run/load .

Is there a way to "refresh" the dom?

```
import React, { useEffect,useState, Suspense } from "react"
import { Link, graphql } from "gatsby"
import Img from "gatsby-image"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import EmbedContainer from "react-oembed-container"
import SEO from "../components/seo"
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet"


const PostContentComponent = React.lazy(() => import('../components/PostContentComponent'));

const BlogPost = ({ data }) => {

  const [scripts,setScripts] = useState([])

  function getScripts () {
 // get all script tags from content
 const re = /<script\b[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/script\b[^>]*>/g
 const results = setScripts(data.strapiPost.content.match(re))
 
 return results
  }
 
  console.log('scripts', scripts)


  useEffect(() => {
    getScripts()
 

    // window.instgrm.Embeds.process()
    // window.twttr.widgets.load()
  }, [data])
  return (
    <>
      <Layout>
        <Helmet>
          {scripts ? scripts.map((script)=> {
           return script  
          }): null}
        </Helmet>
        <SEO title={data.strapiPost.title}/>
        <section className="posts-container mx-auto all-blog-content my-5 sm:my-20 px-5">
          <h3 className="text-1xl sm:text-3xl font-black mb-3">
            {data.strapiPost.title}
          </h3>
      

          <div className="autor flex flex-wrap items-start">
            <div className="autores flex  ">
              <div className="autorInfo flex items-start">
                <h2 className="text-sm tracking-tighter text-gray-900">
                  By{" "}
                  {data.strapiPost.users_permissions_users.length === 1 ? (
                    <>
                      <Link className="hover:text-black transition duration-300 ease-in-out text-xs mr-1">
                        {data.strapiPost.users_permissions_users[0].username}
                      </Link>{" "}
                    </>
                  ) : data.strapiPost.users_permissions_users.length === 2 ? (
                    data.strapiPost.users_permissions_users.map((x, index) => (
                      <>
                        <Link
                         
                          className="hover:text-black transition duration-300 ease-in-out text-xs mr-1"
                        >
                          {x.name} {x.lastname}{" "}
                          {index <
                          data.strapiPost.users_permissions_users.length - 1
                            ? " &"
                            : ""}
                        </Link>
                      </>
                    ))
                  ) : null}
                </h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            {/* LOAD CATEGORIES */}
            <div className="md:ml-5">
              <ul className="flex flex-nowrap relative ">
                {data.strapiPost.categories.map(cat => {
                  return (
                    <Link
                      key={cat.name}
                      
                      className={`bg-gray-200 py-1 px-2 mr-1 rounded-lg text-black text-xs flex-grow `}
                    >
                      {cat.name}
                    </Link>
                  )
                })}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <span className="text-gray-600 mr-3 text-xs">
            Updated at {new Date(data.strapiPost.updated_at).toDateString()}
          </span>

          <div className="posts-content py-10">
            <Img
              alt={data.strapiPost.title}
              key={data.strapiPost.featured_image.childImageSharp.fluid.src}
              imgStyle={{ objectFit: "contain" }}
              fluid={data.strapiPost.featured_image.childImageSharp.fluid}
              className="mb-10"
            />

            <EmbedContainer markup={data.strapiPost.content}>
              <div
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: unescape(data.strapiPost.content) }}
              />
            </EmbedContainer>





          </div>

          {/* end of all posts */}

          {/* AUTHOR CARD */}

          <h3 className="text-2xl font-black text-center my-10">
            Read More posts by this Author{" "}
          </h3>
        </section>

        <section className="posts-container mx-auto">
          <div
            className={`grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-${data.strapiPost.users_permissions_users.length} md:grid-cols-${data.strapiPost.users_permissions_users.length} xl:grid-cols-${data.strapiPost.users_permissions_users.length} gap-4 my-5`}
          >
            {data.strapiPost.users_permissions_users.map((user, index) => {
              return (
                <div
                  key={index}
                  className="bg-purple-50 flex flex-col items-center justify-center bg-white p-4 shadow rounded-lg"
                >
                  <div className="inline-flex shadow-lg border border-gray-200 rounded-full overflow-hidden h-40 w-40">
                    {/* <img
              src="https://platformable.com/content/images/2020/03/headshot-profile.png"
              alt=""
              className="h-full w-full my-0"
            /> */}
                    <Img
                      alt={data.strapiPost.title}
                      key={index}
                      fluid={user.image.childImageSharp.fluid}
                      className="h-full w-full my-0"
                    />
                  </div>

                  <h2 className="mt-4 font-bold text-xl">
                    {user.name} {user.lastname}
                  </h2>
                  <h6 className="mt-2 text-sm font-medium">{user.position}</h6>

                  <p className="text-xs text-gray-500 text-center mt-3">
                    {user.bio}
                  </p>
                </div>
              )
            })}
          </div>
        </section>
      </Layout>
    </>
  )
}

export default BlogPost

export const query = graphql`
  query MyPost($slug: String!) {
    strapiPost(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
      categories {
        name
      }
      content
      id
      title
      users_permissions_users {
        id
        name
        lastname
        username
        image {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
        position
      }
      updated_at
      featured_image {
        childImageSharp {
          fluid {
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: Check the docs for [`onRouteUpdate`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser#onRouteUpdate).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
    <Helmet>
      {scripts && scripts.map((script)=> <script>{script}</script>)}
    </Helmet>
```

*Based on: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/6299#issuecomment-402793089*

Alternatively, you can use the custom hook approach ([`useScript`](https://usehooks.com/useScript/)).